# Not able to paste values with a filter existing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to paste a group of values in a column, but there is a filter on another column. So as I paste the values, the paste action is ignoring the filter, and not pasting the values in the filtered empty cells.
I searched, and found some results mentioning the use of alt+; or "Select visible cells only", but I receive an error as I paste the values, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: See this video mate, it should help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxFEPYdcymU&ab_channel=ContexturesInc.

Comment: Not tackling my issue

Comment: A `VBA` solution could look like the following: 1. a dialog pops up and you are asked to select the source range and press `Ok`, 2. another dialog pops up and you are asked to select the destination (first, any since only the column is important) cell of the destination range and press 'Ok', 3. The data is written appropriately. If that's of interest to you, enable the `vba` tag or just confirm in the comments. If someone else is going to do it, the idea is `Application.InputBox` twice and then each `Area` of the range is copied using `Offset`.